# Firebase rule to target all properties except one

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to write a firebase rule to target all properties except one at a given location. The data is stored as follows

```
users: {
  userId: {
    property1: some_string,
    property2: some_string,
    property3: some_string
  }
}
```

I want to create a `read` rule that always allows reading `property1` and allow reading `property2` and `property3` only if the user is authenticated.

How can I go about writing such a rule?

I guess I can write a rule for each property separately but I wanted to know if there is an easier way to capture `all except few` use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase security rules cannot be used to filter data. Read operations always either fail or succeed. They never return only part of a node.

If you want to make some of the properties of user profiles publicly readable, while others are only readable to authenticated users, you should put the publicly readable properties into a separate top-level node.

For some more examples of this, see:

- [How to create public/private user profile with Firebase security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921824/how-to-create-public-private-user-profile-with-firebase-security-rules)
- [Firebase: How to structure public/private user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data)
- [Firebase security rules, setting a children not readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797909/firebase-security-rules-setting-a-children-not-readable)
- [Denormalizing data structures for private data access in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027844/denormalizing-data-structures-for-private-data-access-in-firebase)